# How can I notify a user that a session is about to expire in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I intend notifying the user 60 seconds before the session expires in asp.net. I would like the user to choose to renew the session or ignore the notification.

How can I achieve this in asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the page loads, you can set a javascript timeout to popup in the appropriate amount of time. It's not perfect, but probably good enough.

```
setTimeout("sessionAlmostGone()", 10 * 5 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

First result from google

[Session.Timeout and Notification Before Session Expire](https://web.archive.org/web/20160425040018/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/AzamSharp/archive/2008/01/05/118269.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP protocol doesn't provides way to push client, only pull allowed. Your task looks as "push" notification to client.

Instead use JScript-based timer on client side that after expiring timeout shows message about renewing session. If so AJAX allows you notify server to prolong or close session.